# Univariate Kalman filtering with factor in state-equation

Tags: kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have a simple Kalman problem: how does one estimate the following local level univariate state-space model, but with some driving factor:

```
y(t) = m(t) + e,                Observation equation
m(t) = m(t-1)+ F(t) + d         State equation

e~iid N(0,V)
d~iid N(0,W)
```

where F(t) is the observed independent factor at time t.

What are the relevant recursive equations for estimating m(t)?

Comment: I believe everything you need is in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), or you can see the tutorial [here](http://aircconline.com/ijcses/V8N1/8117ijcses01.pdf).